# Why do these CartoDB infowindows return "no data available"?

Tags: carto

In my Cartodb map (not the map view of a dataset, but an actual "Map"), I have created custom infowindows for my points, and in Edit mode, they show up great. However, on the published map, when the user clicks on a point, an infowindow shows up that says "No data available."

Here's a screenshot of map editor:
[image]

Here's the published map:
https://uwm-libraries.cartodb.com/viz/c46ab240-bbae-11e5-af70-0e787de82d45/embed_map

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in your image, you have one hided layer on your map. Do you experience the same problem if you remove or show the hided layer in the CartoDB Editor? This problem might be related to this [cartodb.js bug](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/5858)